# How to find the content of Functions or Methods in TA Library?

Tags: python, methods, ta-lib

I am working with Technical Analysis Library (TA lib) and I like to know the content of the methods in this library.

I have a sample code below. How could I find the content of the SMA method in talib?

```
import talib as ta
import pandas as pd

# Reading Stock data from csv file
df = pd.read_csv('./Update_Data_Python/_APPE1.csv')

# Calculate the Moving Average of previous 20 days--> return a series of numbers
ma20_series = ta.SMA(df.Close, 20)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the source code? https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib (you'd also have a copy of it in your `site-packages`). Alternatively, you can use [`inspect.getsource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) if you're trying to do this within Python.

Comment: I use the inspect command and split it by lines, `lines = inspect.getsource(ta).splitlines()`, and I see a list of texts but I can't reach the content of methods. when I put the input like `lines = inspect.getsource(ta.SMA).splitlines()` I get type error.

Comment: That means the implementation of `SMA` is not purely Python. It's likely contained in a compiled library as a C API extension or written in Cython. You'll have to go read the source code directly in Github.

Answer (score 0):

Python's TA-Lib library is just a wrapper for TA-Lib library written in C language. C library is compiled to binary code, so no chance to check what inside at runtime. You may investigate its C sources to find the code behind the methods. The ta-lib wrapper downloads the sources from address: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
You may investigate this archieve or browse the sources online at
https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/
Or you may browse it's fork on GitHub:
https://github.com/TA-Lib/ta-lib

Anyway, for example, the SMA implementation is in ya_SMA.c file at `/ta-lib/src/ta_func/` or `ta-lib/c/src/ta_func/`.

Btw, there is API in Python to get the list of indicators' names and their parameters (input arguments, settings, output arguments etc.) - so called TA-Lib's abstract API. So if you just need to list them and switch between them at runtime there is a way.